# Getting list of files in documents folder

Tags: ios, swift

What is wrong with my code for getting the filenames in the document folder?

```
func listFilesFromDocumentsFolder() -> [NSString]?{
    var theError = NSErrorPointer()
    let dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]
    if dirs != nil {
        let dir = dirs![0] as NSString
        let fileList = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(dir, error: theError) as [NSString]
        return fileList
    }else{
        return nil
    }
}
```

I thought I read the documents correctly and I am very sure about what is in the documents folder, but "fileList" does not show anything? "dir" shows the path to the folder.

Comment: you want to show the names of the files that are in document directory or the files that are in the folders also?

Comment: first, only files in the document folder itself!

Comment: I just ran your code and it worked as expected.  I got a list of what is in my documents directory.  Do we misunderstand your question?

Comment: Strange?
i also used ".fileExistsAtPath(path)" which tells me a specific file is present. But nothing shows up in "fileList"!?

Comment: My list included both directories and files.

Comment: How do you verify whats in the list? I simply looked within the debugger to "fileList". Maybe i better use println()? –  pawi 18 mins ago

Comment: Thanks your your answers! My code also works now!
I don't know what really happened, because it first didn't and i tried to solve it with the debugger, but obviously couldn't read the infos properly. With simple println() i could verify it works!
Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 181, accepted):

This solution works with **Swift 4** (Xcode 9.2) and also with **Swift 5** (Xcode 10.2.1+):

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
do {
    let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    // process files
} catch {
    print("Error while enumerating files \(documentsURL.path): \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Here's a reusable FileManager extension that also lets you skip or include hidden files in the results:

```
import Foundation

extension FileManager {
    func urls(for directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory, skipsHiddenFiles: Bool = true ) -> [URL]? {
        let documentsURL = urls(for: directory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileURLs = try? contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: skipsHiddenFiles ? .skipsHiddenFiles : [] )
        return fileURLs
    }
}

// Usage
print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory) ?? "none")
```

Comment: How can I exclude hidden files?

Comment: It's already exclude by default. If want to include call function like this: `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, skipsHiddenFiles: false)`

Answer (score 304):

**Swift 5**

```
do {
    // Get the document directory url
    let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(
        for: .documentDirectory,
        in: .userDomainMask,
        appropriateFor: nil,
        create: true
    )
    print("documentDirectory", documentDirectory.path)
    // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(
        at: documentDirectory,
        includingPropertiesForKeys: nil
    )
    print("directoryContents:", directoryContents.map { $0.localizedName ?? $0.lastPathComponent })
    for url in directoryContents {
        print(url.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent)
    }
    
    // if you would like to hide the file extension
    for var url in directoryContents {
        url.hasHiddenExtension = true
    }
    for url in directoryContents {
        print(url.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent)
    }

    // if you want to get all mp3 files located at the documents directory:
    let mp3s = directoryContents.filter(\.isMP3).map { $0.localizedName ?? $0.lastPathComponent }
    print("mp3s:", mp3s)
    
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

You would need to add those extensions to your project

```
extension URL {
    var typeIdentifier: String? { (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]))?.typeIdentifier }
    var isMP3: Bool { typeIdentifier == "public.mp3" }
    var localizedName: String? { (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.localizedNameKey]))?.localizedName }
    var hasHiddenExtension: Bool {
        get { (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.hasHiddenExtensionKey]))?.hasHiddenExtension == true }
        set {
            var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
            resourceValues.hasHiddenExtension = newValue
            try? setResourceValues(resourceValues)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For people that are as careless as I am. Note that the call: FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: <#T##String#>) may not work properly for unknown reasons in Swift 3.0. Use the one given above here.

Comment: If I run this on an iCloud Drive directory, it only returns items that have been downloaded to the device - is there any way to get the URLs of all items without downloading them first?

Comment: @mralexhay it shows it for me even the items that are not downloaded. It should  show a dot `.` prefix and a `.cloud` suffix in the file name. try `let icloudFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "icloud" }` it should show the files that are not downloaded

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the reply - I hadn't realised it prepends the ".", I thought it just had the "iCloud" suffix. I realised I wasn't returning hidden files - no wonder they didn't show! Thanks again.

Answer (score 21):

A shorter syntax for SWIFT 3

```
func listFilesFromDocumentsFolder() -> [String]?
{
    let fileMngr = FileManager.default;

    // Full path to documents directory
    let docs = fileMngr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].path

    // List all contents of directory and return as [String] OR nil if failed
    return try? fileMngr.contentsOfDirectory(atPath:docs)
}
```

Usage example:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    print(listFilesFromDocumentsFolder())
}
```

Tested on xCode 8.2.3 for iPhone 7 with iOS 10.2 & iPad with iOS 9.3

Answer (score 9):

Apple states about [`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1414224-nssearchpathfordirectoriesindoma):

> You should consider using the `FileManager` methods `urls(for:in:)` and `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)` which return URLs, which are the preferred format.

---

With Swift 5, `FileManager` has a method called [`contentsOfDirectory(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1413768-contentsofdirectory). `contentsOfDirectory(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)` has the following declaration:

> Performs a shallow search of the specified directory and returns URLs for the contained items.

```
func contentsOfDirectory(at url: URL, includingPropertiesForKeys keys: [URLResourceKey]?, options mask: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions = []) throws -> [URL]
```

---

Therefore, in order to retrieve the urls of the files contained in documents directory, you can use the following code snippet that uses `FileManager`'s `urls(for:in:)` and `contentsOfDirectory(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)` methods:

```
guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }

do {
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])

    // Print the urls of the files contained in the documents directory
    print(directoryContents)
} catch {
    print("Could not search for urls of files in documents directory: \(error)")
}
```

---

As an example, the `UIViewController` implementation below shows how to save a file from app bundle to documents directory and how to get the urls of the files saved in documents directory:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func copyFile(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Get file url
        guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Movie", withExtension: "mov") else { return }

        // Create a destination url in document directory for file
        guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
        let documentDirectoryFileUrl = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Movie.mov")

        // Copy file to document directory
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentDirectoryFileUrl.path) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: fileUrl, to: documentDirectoryFileUrl)
                print("Copy item succeeded")
            } catch {
                print("Could not copy file: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func displayUrls(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }

        do {
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])

            // Print the urls of the files contained in the documents directory
            print(directoryContents) // may print [] or [file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/Movie.mov]
        } catch {
            print("Could not search for urls of files in documents directory: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Simple and dynamic solution (Swift 5):

```
extension FileManager {

  class func directoryUrl() -> URL? {
      let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
      return paths.first
  }

  class func allRecordedData() -> [URL]? {
     if let documentsUrl = FileManager.directoryUrl() {
        do {
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
            return directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "m4a" }
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
     }
     return nil
  }}
```

Answer (score 7):

This code prints out all the directories and files in my documents directory:

Some modification of your function:

```
func listFilesFromDocumentsFolder() -> [String]
{
    let dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)
    if dirs != [] {
        let dir = dirs[0]
        let fileList = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: dir)
        return fileList
    }else{
        let fileList = [""]
        return fileList
    }
}
```

Which gets called by:

```
    let fileManager:FileManager = FileManager.default
    let fileList = listFilesFromDocumentsFolder()

    let count = fileList.count

    for i in 0..<count
    {
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileList[i]) != true
        {
            print("File is \(fileList[i])")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 2.0 Compability

```
func listWithFilter () {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
           // We need just to get the documents folder url
    let documentsUrl = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL

    do {
    // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
    if let directoryUrls = try? NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants) {
        print(directoryUrls)
       ........
        }

    }

}
```

OR

```
 func listFiles() -> [String] {

    var theError = NSErrorPointer()
    let dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]
    if dirs != nil {
        let dir = dirs![0]
        do {
        let fileList = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(dir)
        return fileList as [String]
        }catch {

        }

    }else{
        let fileList = [""]
        return fileList
    }
    let fileList = [""]
    return fileList

}
```