# Swift: Is there an OS agnostic way to get the home directory?

Tags: swift, linux, macos

See title. I want to create the data files for my CLI application preferably in `~/` or `~/config`, but predefined Swift `FileManager.default.url()` doesn't seem to have it.

`.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser` seems to be available only for macOS Sierra and later.

Any ideas?

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/41384443/1187415.

Comment: I thought `NS` classes would require AppKit. I was wrong apparently. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser` or you only refer to the documentation?

`FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser` seems to be available at least in Swift 5.9.1 on Linux. I have not tried the earliest version.

I have checked the source code of Swift Framework and the implementation seems to have be done 8 years ago (so in the early version of Swift): https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blame/1c929e5fa58676afeaecc75c2cdeca5091bf8bbc/CoreFoundation/Base.subproj/CFPlatform.c#L480