# How can I run macOS terminal commands from Swift?

Tags: swift, terminal

I want be able to run this code through Swift for Terminal in macOS:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
mkdir "New Folder"
```

Basically I want to go to level of desktop then create a new Folder there. I want press a button in Swift/SwiftUI to run a function to execute the code for Terminal. Using Swift/SwiftUI is just for UI. I do not have shell file saved some where, all my codes is that I want be able to run those 2 commands for Terminal from Swift.

```
func runBashCode() {

    // need help here
    cd ~/Desktop/
    mkdir "New Folder"

}
```

Comment: Why (use bash for this)?  While not use `FileManager`?

Comment: I do not understand what you said, you mean that I should use bash?

Comment: No, I mean why execute a shell command to create a directory when a API already exists to handle file level operations - [plenty of examples available](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=swift+make+directory&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: Oh, that is the nature of question, as I mentioned in my question. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @jnpdx: Are you a pro in bash? I am not, but I know enough that bash need a saved shell to works! Do you see a shell file or mentioning about a saved shell some where?

Comment: @ioscoder I don't understand, sorry, but you want to create a directory?  Why not use the `FileManager` API available in Swing?  Why do you "need" to execute `mkdir` via the terminal directly?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I do not understand your question about asking why either, I simply mentioned in my question that swift/swiftUI is JUST for UI, how ever you commented about using the native way of swift for making a directory! Am I missing something there to add to my question?

Comment: @ioscoder [Execute shell/bash commands from Swift](https://gist.github.com/andreacipriani/8c3af3719da31c8fae2cdfa8c21e17ba).  You will need to make use of `Process#currentDirectory` to "set the current directory"

Comment: I have dabbled in it and [this](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone) does it. If you go though the code you’ll see the shell scripts and how they are run. Apple has shell scripts pretty locked down. You’ll have to play with submission. I remove the scripts prior to submission because it will fail. There may be a way to get them approved but I am not sure of the process.

Comment: @jnpdx: You can answer my question, I would accept it if I could run those commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

Note: you need to delete the "App Sandbox" in the "Signing & Capabilities"

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let arg = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Desktop/newfolder"
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("mkdir") {
            runMkdir()
        }.frame(width: 333, height: 333)
    }
    
    func runMkdir() {
        let task = Process()
        task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/mkdir")
        task.arguments = [arg]
        task.launch()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Don’t hardcode your path. This will only work at the machine which the app is being developed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41384443/2303865

Comment: yes, good point. This is just an example. I'll update my answer with your suggestion.