# FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory fail in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I have code in objective -c that is like:

```
- (NSArray *)PDFInDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *dirContents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath
                                                            error:nil];
    return [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:self.pdfPredicate];
}
```

that I want translated into swift 3 in this way:

```
func PDFInDirectory(directoryPath: String) -> NSArray {
     let dirContents = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: directoryPath) as NSArray
     return dirContents!.filtered(using: ppdfPredicate()) as NSArray
}
```

but when I run it fail in the line:

```
let dirContents = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: directoryPath) as NSArray
```

Here is all code:

```
import UIKit

class PdfFilePicker: UITableViewController {
    // Variable 
    var NNOTIFICATION_NAME_SELECTED_PDF = "VSSelectedPDFFile"
    var documentsDirectory = ""
    var inboxDirectory = ""
    var pdfPredicate: NSPredicate?
    var pdfFiles: NSMutableArray = []
    func ddocumentsDirectory() -> String {
        if self.documentsDirectory == "" {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
            self.documentsDirectory = paths.object(at: 0) as! String
        }
        print("Document directory call")
    return documentsDirectory
    }

    func ppdfPredicate() -> NSPredicate {

        if self.pdfPredicate == nil {
            self.pdfPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "self ENDSWITH '.pdf'")
        }
        return pdfPredicate!
    }
    func ppdfFiles() -> NSMutableArray {
        if self.pdfFiles == [] {
            self.pdfFiles = [20]
        }
        return  pdfFiles
    }
    func PDFInDirectory(directoryPath: String) -> NSArray {
        // Here is the probelm.
        print("My dir is \(directoryPath)")
        do {
            let dirContents = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: directoryPath) as NSArray
            print("my dirContents \(dirContents)")
            return dirContents!.filtered(using: ppdfPredicate()) as NSArray
        } catch {
            print("my dirPath \(directoryPath)")
        }
        return []
    }
    func populateAllPdfsFromDocumentsAndInboxDirectory() {
        self.ppdfFiles().removeAllObjects()
        self.populatePDFfilesInFolder(path: self.ddocumentsDirectory())
        let inboxDirectory : String = URL(fileURLWithPath: self.ddocumentsDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Inbox").absoluteString
        self.populatePDFfilesInFolder(path: inboxDirectory)
        self.sortPdfFilesArray()
    }
    // Finished until here. // Checkif it crash probably yes
    func populatePDFfilesInFolder(path: String) {
        var isDir: ObjCBool = false
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let isExist = fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path, isDirectory: &isDir)
        if isExist == false   {
            print("Read file manager successfully")
            let array = self.PDFInDirectory(directoryPath: path)
            print("PDF Steve")
            if array.count > 0 {
                for fileName: String in array as! Array {
                    let test : String = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).appendingPathComponent(fileName).absoluteString
                    self.ppdfFiles().adding(test)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Can be crash in closure
    func sortPdfFilesArray() {
        if self.ppdfFiles().count > 0 {
            self.ppdfFiles().sort(comparator: {( a: Any, b: Any) -> ComparisonResult in
                if !(a is String) || !(b is String) {
                  return ((a as! String).compare(b as! String))
                } else {
                    let aString: String? = (a as? String)
                    let bString: String? = (b as? String)
                    return (aString?.compare(bString!, options: .caseInsensitive))!
                }
            })
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = NSLocalizedString("SELECT_PDF", comment: "")
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.populateAllPdfsFromDocumentsAndInboxDirectory()
    }
    // Steve Note: Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.ppdfFiles().count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
        // steve note Not sure about object
        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Icon-PDF.png")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = (self.ppdfFiles().object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).lastPathComponent
        return cell!
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: NNOTIFICATION_NAME_SELECTED_PDF), object: self.ppdfFiles().object(at: indexPath.row))
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            self.deleteFile(atPath: self.ppdfFiles().object(at: indexPath.row) as! String)
            self.ppdfFiles().removeObject(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    func deleteFile(atPath path: String) {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path, isDirectory: nil) {
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: path)
            } catch {
                print("File Manager Remove Item at Path crash")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You are probably passing an invalid path String. Can you post the path you are using?

Comment: Hi @LeoDabus, I just post all the code below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27722526/2303865

Comment: the problem is that you are using absoluteString to get the fileURL path. Change `.absoluteString` to `.path`

Comment: If the answer of the duplicate question link above doesn't solve your problem let me know so I can reopen your question.

Comment: @LeoDabus, I changed but still it shows nil.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question narrowing your problem. No need to post your whole code

Answer (score 3):

**Updated example**

You need to catch the exceptions that may be generated whenever you use 'try'
Here's an example that I'm using in a current project.  I have a number of files stored in a folder called `templates` and this code **does** return an array of filenames - provided there is actually something there already

```
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectory = dirPaths[0]
    let folder = documentDirectory.appending("/templates")

    do
    {
        let fileList = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: folder)
        for file in fileList
        {
            fileListArray.append(file)
        }
        return fileListArray
    }
    catch
    {
        addLogText(error.localizedDescription)
        return []
    }
```

It might be worth checking that you're writing your files into the same directory that you're reading them from - have you tried confirming that the files have been created and then reading them immediately?