# Userdefault Save and Read URL FilePath

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, filepath, pdfkit

I Download pdf file Like This And Saved the **Path** in Userdefault
     **var documents = PDFDocument**

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let fileName = urlString as NSString;
var arrayUrl = [String]()
arrayUrl.append(filePath)
self.defaults.set(arrayUrl, forKey: Constants.myKeyURL)
```

The First Time when App Run This **documents** get Value Well But Next Time When I don't need to Download Again documents it's Null but The ArrayURL ints same Value !!

```
var arrayUrl = [String]()

self.defaults.stringArray(forKey: Constants.myKeyURL)
arrayUrl = self.defaults.stringArray(forKey: Constants.myKeyURL)!

self.documents = arrayUrl.flatMap { PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: $0) ) }

print(self.documents)

DispatchQueue.main.async {

self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: You should also read the comments posted in your previous question and the edit was made to the accepted answer which already warned you about your current issue

Comment: Note that would be much easier to simply use FileManager cotentsOfDirectory method to list your pdf documents located at your document directory when needed. No need to save anything to user defaults. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721418/getting-list-of-files-in-documents-folder/27722526?s=1|64.9724#27722526

Comment: @LeoDabus I Need to use the UserDefault 
Because after I need to Reorder or Something like this can you help me more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't save the file's fullpath, for security reasons your app's container name gets changed, so the document directory would also changed every time your app gets launched/reloaded.

Instead, save only the file's name along its extension (use the property `lastPathComponent` from the downloaded url), and whenever you want to load these files just append the name to the document directory.

Comment: how to Save lastPathComponent and take back this for read Please help me     let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
                 let fileName = urlString as NSString;
                let filePath="\(documentsPath)/\(fileName.lastPathComponent)";
                let fileExists = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: filePath)